# Read Clob from JayBeDeAPI Query

Tags: python, oracle, jaydebeapi

I'm using python's jaybedeapi to connect to an Oracle database. Everything seems to be working fine, except when I encounter fields with `oracle.sql.clob` data:

Connection & query:

```
conn = jaydebeapi.connect('oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver','jdbc:oracle:thin:user/pass@host:port:db')

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("select * from table")

data = cur.fetchmany(size=10)

print data[0][1]
```

Returning:

`<jpype._jclass.oracle.sql.CLOB at 0x5fe83d543c92>`

How can I print the value in these fields?

EDIT:

I prefer not to explicitly call out each field `DBMS_LOB.substr(field,3000)` in the select statement (which works). If possible, I'd rather have a solution directly in python.

Comment: Can you please try [this feature branch](https://github.com/baztian/jaydebeapi/tree/feature/advanced-datatypes)?

Comment: I've tried it myself and I have to admin that it doesn't work currently. But please see [this comment to a jaydebeapi issue](https://github.com/baztian/jaydebeapi/issues/6#issuecomment-112553645) which might help.

Comment: Yea, it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 5):

This just worked for me:

```
db_result = data[0][1]
print db_result.getSubString(1, db_result.length())
```

I'm using jaydebeapi version 0.2.0 and jpype 0.5.7, Python 2.7.10/32 on Win 7/64.  Found the solution here: http://almostflan.com/t/embedclob/ though I didn't have the autocommit issue he did.